# Wrapping np.arrays __pow__ method

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I was just revisiting some of my code to improve the performance and stumpled over something strange:

```
a = np.linspace(10,1000,1000000).reshape(1000,1000)

%timeit np.square(a)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.07 ms per loop

%timeit a*a
100 loops, best of 3: 8.18 ms per loop

%timeit a**2
100 loops, best of 3: 8.32 ms per loop
```

Ok it seems to have some overhead when using the power-operator (`**`) but otherwise they seem identical (I guess NumPy is doing that) but then it got strange:

```
In [46]: %timeit np.power(a, 2)
10 loops, best of 3: 121 ms per loop
```

So there is no problem but it seems a bit inconsistent to have a fallback for the magic pow but not for the UFUNC. But then I got interested since I am using third powers a lot:

```
%timeit a*a*a
100 loops, best of 3: 18.1 ms per loop

%timeit a**3
10 loops, best of 3: 121 ms per loop

%timeit np.power(a, 3)
10 loops, best of 3: 121 ms per loop
```

There seems to be no "shortcut" in the third power and UFUNC and 'magic-pow' work the same (at least in regard to performance).

But that's not that good since I want a consistent method of using powers in my code and I'm not quite sure how to wrap the `__pow__` of numpy.

## So to get to the point, my question is :

Is there a way I can wrap the numpys `__pow__` method? Because I want a consistent way of writing powers in my script not writing `a**2` and at another place `power(a, 3)`. Simply writing `a**3`, and redirecting this to my power function, would be preferred (but for that I would need to somehow wrap the ndarrays `__pow__` or?). 
Currently I am using a shortcut but that's not that beautiful (I even have to declare the exponent==2 case since `np.power` performs not optimal there):

```
def power(array, exponent):
    if exponent == 2: #catch this, or it calls the slow np.power(array, exponent)
        return np.square(array)
    if exponent == 3:
        return array * array * array
    #As soon as np.cbrt is avaiable catch the exponent 4/3 here too
    return np.power(array, exponent) 

%timeit power(a, 3)
100 loops, best of 3: 17.8 ms per loop
%timeit a**3
10 loops, best of 3: 121 ms per loop
```

I am using NumPy v1.9.3 and I do not want to subclass `np.ndarray` just for wrapping the `__pow__` method. :-)

EDIT: I rewrote the part where I get to my question. To clarify it: I am not asking about why NumPy does it the way it does - that is just to explain why I ask the question.

Comment: Do you really want to micro-optimize the power operator for the square case because it’s a bit faster? That seems really overoptimized to me; especially if it means introducing another function. Just use `** n` all the time, and don’t worry about that small time difference

Comment: np.all(a**3 - a\*a\*a < 1e-6) -> True so I think it's the same, for numpy you have to declare it a matrix to trigger matrix multiplication. And yes the question is how to wrap \_\_pow__. And the time difference is big in my case since I deal with lots of those really big arrays (1000 1000x2000 images). Sorry for the edits, I'm quite new and do not get the text formatting right.

Comment: It is not possible to modify the `__pow__` method of an ndarray without using subclasses. You could (as you've suggested) write another function. If you're concerned about performance, you could use a library like [numexpr](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr) which has an optimised power function. For instance, `numexpr.evaluate("a**3")` is around 20x faster than `a*a*a`.

Comment: As an aside, I posted an issue about the discrepancy between `a**2` and `np.power(a, 2)` [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6399).

Comment: I feared so, I hoped there was some way with `functools` that I have missed, but thanks for the hint about numexpr. If I have to write a special function that optimizes the performance the factor 2 (unfortunatly I do not get 20) cannot be denied. Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer with extending numpy ndarray class, and also timings for the numexpr library as suggested by @ajcr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good catch. I too wonder why is that behavior. But to be short and concise answering the question, I would just do:

```
def mypower(array, exponent):
    return reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, [array for _ in range(exponent)])


%timeit mypower(a,2)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.68 ms per loop

%timeit mypower(a,3)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.09 ms per loop

%timeit mypower(a,4)
100 loops, best of 3: 12.6 ms per loop
```

Obsviouly the overhead increases with the exponent but for low ones is better than 10x the time.

**Note** that this is different from the original numpy implementation which is not specific for a numeric exponent and supports an array of exponents as the second argument ([check it out here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.power.html#numpy.power)).

**Overloading the operator**

The way to do what you want is to subclass ndarray and use views. See the following example:

```
import numexpr
import numpy as np
​
class MyArray(np.ndarray):
    def __pow__(self, other):
        return reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, [self for _ in range(other)])
​
class NumExprArray(np.ndarray):
    def __pow__(self, other):
        return numexpr.evaluate("self**%f" % other)
        #This implies extra overhead, is as much as 4x slower:
        #return numexpr.evaluate("self**other")

a = np.linspace(10,1000,1000000).reshape(1000,1000).view(MyArray)
na = np.linspace(10,1000,1000000).reshape(1000,1000).view(NumExprArray)
​
%timeit a**2
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.2 ms per loop

%timeit na**2
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.14 ms per loop

%timeit a**3
100 loops, best of 3: 4.69 ms per loop

%timeit na**3
100 loops, best of 3: 2.36 ms per loop

%timeit a**4
100 loops, best of 3: 6.59 ms per loop

%timeit na**4
100 loops, best of 3: 2.4 ms per loop
```

For more information on this method please follow this [link](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html). Another way would be to use a [custom infix operator](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/infix/) but for readability purposes is not so good. As one can see, numexpr should be the way to go.

Comment: sorry, your answer is good but I wanted to wrap the np.ndarray \_\_pow__ function somehow (if this is possible), so I can simply write a\*\*x which I think is the nicest way to read the code. That i'm exploiting some assumptions about my data (real numbers as data and only 2, 3 and 4/3 as exponent) could mean it may breaks somewhere else but since this is just for my personal use this will not matter much (hopefully)

Comment: exponentiation by squaring would be faster for larger powers, numexpr seems to do that as you can see in the timings of **3 and **4

Comment: Thanks for the info about that view-cast. It's actually an additional overhead for creating the array but in the end I like that approach most. The link you provided is quite lengthy and it seems nontrivial to subclass ndarray - which was the reason I originally did not want to do it - but maybe it is just this easy.

Comment: Just to be clear, the reduce you use in your answer is the one that was 'exported' to `functools` in python3?

Comment: Yes, the reduce function has been moved since in most use cases it is the same as a simple for loop, which is more readable in general. I have updated the example with timings from a more reliable machine, and completed the example using numexpr.

Answer (score 3):

If I read the [source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/0b0206c1617841ed2e5324de752ee8ede2cce791/numpy/core/src/multiarray/number.c#L494) correctly, when `numpy` performs power, it checks whether the numerical value of the exponent is one of the special cases (-0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, and 2).  If so, the operation is done using special routines.  All other numerical values of the exponent are considered "general", and will be fed into the generic power function, which may be slow (especially if the exponent is promoted to floating-point type, but I'm not sure if this is the case with `a ** 3`).

Comment: Sorry, maybe I did something wrong in posting my question but I am not asking about why numpy does it this way. In my experience numpy does most things as good as possible. I am asking about a way to redirect pythons call to numpy.ndarray.\_\_pow__, when calling a**x, to my power-function, which catches my promoted cases and optimizes them and if it can't it throws them back to numpy.