# Namespace confusion and wrapping

Tags: python, numpy, namespaces

propably this question was asked before but I found nothing about it so far.

Suppose I have some code in a file called test.py (that was a result from my question yesterday [Wrapping np.arrays __pow__ method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32903967/wrapping-np-arrays-pow-method))

```
import numpy as np
from functools import wraps, reduce

#Create a subclass of np.ndarray to speed up the power operation
class MyArray(np.ndarray):
  def __pow__(self, other):
    return reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, [self for _ in range(other)])

#Create a wrapper so that arrays are created using my Class instead of the old one.    
def change_ndarray(func):
  @wraps(func)
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    return func(*args, **kwargs).view(MyArray)
  return wrapper    

np.array = change_ndarray(np.array)
```

So far it worked great in my file every array was produced using the wrapped np.array. But then to compare the speed gain I was confused:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> %timeit np.linspace(10,1000,1000000)**3
10 loops, best of 3: 154 ms per loop
>>> import test
>>> %timeit np.linspace(10,1000,1000000)**3
10 loops, best of 3: 40.6 ms per loop
```

How come the linspace now works with the wrapped ndarray instead of the old one? How does it come that `np.linspace` now calls `t.np.array`? I thought that was another namespace and what does linspace have to do with np.array?

As a note I read through https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html but that's really tough reading and so maybe I have missed it in there. I would be happy if anyone could give me a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *test.py*, `np.array = change_ndarray(np.array)` reassigns the `array` variable in the `numpy` module that you aliased as `np`. All code using `numpy.array` now use the new thing you put in it. Actions such as `from numpy import *` create new variables in the local module, but `import numpy as np` only gives you a reference to the module itself.

Consider how python variables work. Namespaces are python *dicts* that store key (variable name) / value (the object referenced by the variable) pairs. Namespaces are associated with things like methods and functions (local variables), classes (class variables) and modules (module global variables). When you use a variable, python pokes about in several namespace *dicts* looking for the name and returns its object. `np.array` means lookup a variable called `np`, get its namespace *dict* and then look `array` up there. In your case, `np` is the *numpy* module and `array` is a vvariable there.

Comment: Ok, that might explain it. I was confused because np.linspace imported `from .numeric import array` what would be, like you said, another variable that stores the array module while being unaffected by my general wrapper. Actually changing my `test.py` to `from numpy import array` and only wrapping `array` worked as expected. But why did linspace import my wrapped array? Ok your edit actually explained it. Thanks!

Comment: @MSeifert - It didn't. You imported _numpy_ so your module and _numpy_ are both resident. You reassigned `numpy.array` to your wrapper class. That means that the _array_ variable in the _numpy_ namespace dict references your wrapper and not the original class. All code looking up "array" in the _numpy_ namespace will see your wrapper - and that includes code in _numpy_ itself. Unless you are trying to change the behavior of _numpy_ itself, you should not reassign its variables.

Comment: So if I only want to wrap it in the `test.py` and don't want to change numpys array behaviour somewhere else I have to change it to `from numpy import array` and change the wrapper to `array = change_ndarray(array)`?

Comment: @MSeifert - no, all you need is `array = change_ndarray(np.array)`, you don't need to change how you import _numpy_. _np.array_ will continue to be the original _numpy_ class and `array` will be your wrapper class.